# Import OpenCV sdk to Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to import OpenCV 4.1.0 sdk in Android Studio, but I'm getting an error from Android Studio. I searched for the solution for this issue but didn't found any solution. I followed so many tutorial and they followed same step to integrate the OpenCV. At last I am following this url to integrate it but getting the error.

https://medium.com/@kashafahmed/a-proper-beginners-guide-to-installing-opencv-android-in-android-studio-updated-5fe7f3399e1c

Below is the error image

[image]

Help me on this, I'm stuck on it from one week.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed use OpenCV 4.5.5, the referenced tutorial is for a very old OpenCV and Android Studio versions.

Also 4.1.0 is very old as well (2019-04-08) and won't have kept up with the Android Studio/gradle changes google have done since then

There was a minor issue with 4.5.5 still and Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Note there are instruction in the OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\build.gradle file.

The import fails because the 'kotlin-android' plugin used in the OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\build.gradle has been renamed.

So after import has failed, edit the opencv's Module build.gradle and change:-

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`

to

`apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'`

Also In the opencv's Module build.gradle update the

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 26 to a level Android Studio will accept i.e 31

Also in the Project's build.gradle file add the line to the plugins section

`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false`

This for me gets gradle to sync without error and able to build an App.

Also note that you can just open the SDK download as an Android Project and this works for 4.5.5 and then build the sample Apps as well.

Note that I see that OpenCV 4.6.0 has some Android updates for gradle that might make it easier to import (Not tested)